# How to resize font in EditText

Tags: android

I am finding the text in an EditText view overflows off the end. I really would like the font size to readjust (the way it does on iOS) so all the text is visible inside the view. 
THe text is not flowing onto a second line it is restricted to one line but is going off the end out of view.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that Android supports auto-resizing text to fit within the bounds of a `TextView` (or an `EditText`). It's sad, but true...

That being said, you can definitely implement this functionality yourself. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672/844882) for more information on how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

try this below in your xml:

android:singleLine="true"
android:textSize="18sp"